# Can I enable USB debugging on Fig Flip II (Kosher OS)?

Tags: settings, usb-debugging, developer-options

I have Fig Flip II running on Kosher OS (Android 11) on which Developer Options is blocked, so when I press the build number 7 times, nothing happens.

I can't install apps on the phone. When I try opening an APK file it says 'APK not allowed', but it does have a package installer - so I can't install a USB debugging app.

Is there a way for me to enable USB Debugging on this phone?

Comment: There are apps that can directly open developer options settings page. T his should work no matter if you have activated developer options or not.

Comment: @Robert Is it an app that I would have to install? Because my phone only comes with basic apps, and I can't install any more.

Comment: @Robert I added in why I can't install apps. The phone is the Fig Flip II, but nobody has heard of it - its a really small company.

Comment: Does your phone have `Settings -> Security / Privacy ->Install from Unknown Sources`?

Comment: Found [this thread](https://forums.apps4flip.com/d/390-new-fig-kosher-phone/331) discussing about this phone and how it's heavily customized. This looks like a very locked OS like [tag:gabb] phones all over again...

Comment: @RohitGupta No, it doesn't.

Comment: If you are willing to tinker a bit, you may try to enter some sort of flash mode via holding either or both volume keys and the power button while the device is shut down. From there, you may try creating a custom recovery (not for typical end users) or use tools to extract out the userdata partition for adding apps and editing settings.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a way to enable USB debugging, the manufacturer will see that as a bug. It seems that some Hasidic Jews see the Internet as a [major danger to their culture](https://friedavizel.com/2018/08/21/from-quora-what-are-the-internet-usage-restrictions-among-hasidic-jews/), but feel that mobile telephony and GPS navigation are OK and useful.

There is thus a market for Kosher phones, which provide the acceptable features without the problematic ones. Other companies distributing those include [Kosher Cell](https://koshercell.org/), [Planet Cell](https://planetcellny.com/collections/kosher-phones), [Safe Cell](https://www.thesafecell.com/), and [Kosher Mobile](https://koshermobile.com/).

Most of these phones are normal Android or iOS devices with filtering software installed. [Fig Kosher](https://figkosher.com/) appears to do the job more thoroughly, with a customised version of Android, "[KosherOS](https://kosheros.com/)", which leaves out problematic features.

It appears that users of Kosher smartphones have problems with temptation, or fear that their teenage children will be tempted, so these phones are tightly locked down. Allowing USB debugging would run the risk of phone users being able to install apps, such as a web browser, via `adb install`, and preventing that is the whole point of Kosher OS.

Do Fig phones get security updates? The KosherOS on them seems to be based on Android 11, which left support in February 2024. There is a later KosherOS based on Android 13, but there's no mention of it on the Fig website.