# How to get USB debugging on ZTE Z233VL?

Tags: usb-debugging, zte

I've been trying to get USB debugging on the ZTE Z233VL, to possibly install apps. The issue is that I've been trying to look up "Where does Android keep the configuration on if USB debugging is enabled", and all it tells me is how to enable USB debugging on every Android device but this one.

Most of the Android test codes don't work, no debugging features work, and the APK package installer app (the GUI for the installer, not the "pm" tool) isn't bundled. It shows the icon for the app, but it doesn't have a program to run it, it says. Also, it has no WiFi.

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. I'm afraid this situation looks similar to other Android-based flip phones like [Can I enable USB debugging on Fig Flip II (Kosher OS)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/252123/44325)

Comment: This phone is like complete Android, but it's been stripped of some of the features for installing apps.

Answer (score 2):

So I looked up the model and a [ZTE Z233VL](https://support.tracfone.com/en/brands/ZTE/TFZEZ233VL/) is a flip-phone based on Android OS.

Android OS is open-source which means that any manufacturer can create a Custom ROM and use it for their devices. However if the manufacturer wants the Google Play Store they need to enable things like developer mode and `adb` so that Android application developers can test their apps on the device.

What this also means is that if the manufacturer *doesn't* use the Google Play Store, they have no obligation to add in the side-loading or developer mode options.

**TL;DR:**

- While the phone runs Android it isn't running Google Play Services supported Android.
- The manufacturer doesn't need to add in side-loading as they are using a custom ROM and from your account they didn't add side-loading or developer mode.
- Unless someone finds a way in, you won't be able to side-load apps or enable developer mode.

Comment: According to the manual the phone has only 512 GB RAM and 4 GB flash. So I would assume the OS is an Android 2.x OS stripped down to the bones, just the minimum to provide the UI and apps like settings, camera and a gallery, phone, contacts https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/HiEAAOSwAK9iPz-2/s-l1600.jpg

Comment: @Robert For reference I have a different model Android based flip-phone with 4GB storage. My device states it is Android 8.1, and similarly only the most basic of apps along with a carrier store. Probably an [Android Go variant](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/androidgo).

Comment: This phone runs Android 4. The reason I know that, is because it's in some piece of version info I found, hold on...
Also, the device has a way to push updates to it via ADB. I could try that, but it's risky.